# Are there around S$800 billion unaccounted for in Singapore's public finances?

Tags: government, finance, singapore

Christopher Balding, an [associate professor at Peking University](http://english.phbs.pku.edu.cn/index.php?m=content&c=index&a=show&catid=627&id=1), claims in [this note](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2657386) that

> Given publicly available economic data on Singaporean finances, there is an expected asset gap of more than $800 billion SGD unaccounted for from historical surpluses and financing operations when factoring in claimed interest.

Here is [the accompanying Excel spreadsheet with the data](http://www.baldingsworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Singapore-Master-090815-PUBLIC.xlsx).
Here are Balding's [blog posts on Singapore](http://www.baldingsworld.com/tag/singapore/).

To my knowledge, these claims of his have received no coverage by the state-controlled media in Singapore. And I can find no serious, in-depth discussion anywhere of the merits and flaws of Balding's claims. So are his claims correct?

Note that S$800b is about 200% of Singapore's annual GDP. In comparison, 200% of US GDP would be US$36 trillion.

Comment: @KitSunde The "note" as described by the author is not in fact merely that, but it is in fact a [journal preprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Science_Research_Network) in a similar vein to arXiv for physics. I would argue that the paper, as well as the credentials of the author, make it a notable claim.

Comment: Arxiv isn't a real journal. However I see no problem with the analysis.